# Selenium C# завершает свою работу

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте! Делаю приложение используя Selenium C#. Столкнулся с такой ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такое может происходить? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Приложение на Selenium? C# на Ubuntu? ШтА?

Comment: @Nakilon Да, на ubuntu:D Я пишу код используя Monodevelop.

Comment: Почему не взять более работоспособную для этого ОС?

Comment: @Nakilon у меня были на это причины. На windows у меня даже запустится программа не могла, так что я уже радуюсь)

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже что не может достучатся к браузеру. На винде подобное может быть если несовместимая версия браузера к драйверу. 
Или закрыт порт.

В общем и целом, я не советую этим заниматся под убунтой. Это и под виндой может быть проблемно, особенно с последними версиями селениум/браузеров... Что уж говорить про линукс...